# How to solve this SQL use case?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL use case to execute.

Write a query to find the pay date for the month. Pay date is the last Friday of every month .Display the date in the format for eg. Twenty Eighth of January, 2002. Label the heading as Pay date.

Can anyone can help me with its solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks like homework.  Have you tried solving this yourself before you posted a question here?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried doing it but I am getting error in while using CASES (WHEN......THEN).

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can give me hint or method to solve this...

Answer (score 1):

```
select
(CASE
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(LAST_DAY(NOW())) = 1 THEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(LAST_DAY(NOW())) > 6 THEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(LAST_DAY(NOW())) < 6 THEN FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(LAST_DAY(NOW())-7+(6-DAYOFWEEK(LAST_DAY(NOW()))))
    ELSE LAST_DAY(NOW())
 END
 ) as "Pay date"
 from table limit 1
```

Something like this. You should just replace NOW() with your date.

Answer (score 0):

try this below logic-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=847c2e6ed643debf0412abdb837096bf)

```
SET @day = '2020-02-11';

SELECT 
DATE_SUB(@day,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@day)-1 DAY) first_day_month,
DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB(@day,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@day)-1 DAY)) day_of_week,
ADDDATE( 
    DATE_SUB(@day,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@day)-1 DAY), 
    (
        IF(
            DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB(@day,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@day)-1 DAY)) = 7,
            6,
            6-DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB(@day,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@day)-1 DAY))
        )
    )
) as first_friday
```